# still getting Received fatal alert: bad_certificate ,

Tags: java, spring, ssl, pem, jks

i have key and cert (combined) into one cert.pem file , 
and i getting , 
"exception": "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException",
"message": "Received fatal alert: bad_certificate",
`pem file is right,  but i think problem is how i generating jks keystore file.`

### .pem cert format

> #### BEGIN CERTIFICATE
>
> ...
>
> #### END CERTIFICATE
>
> #### BEGIN CERTIFICATE
>
> ...
>
> #### END CERTIFICATE
>
> #### BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
>
> ...
>
> #### END RSA PRIVATE KEY###`

### combine it with keytool comand comand is

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias yourdomain -file combined.pem -keystore yourkeystore.jks`

### java code is

```
public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[]{};
    }
}
```

### request is

```
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(
      new File(this.resourcePath()+"/path_to.jks")
  );
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()) // use null as second param if you don't have a separate key password
            .build();

    sslContext.init(null,new X509TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());


    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(
            new HttpPost("https://url")
    );
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Apache `SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial().build()` it initializes the built context with the specified keystore and the default trustmanager. You then call `sslContext.init()` to **re**-initialize it with *no* keymanager and the specified trustmanager; this ignores and discards the prior initialization. As a result your context has no keymanager, and cannot do client auth.

You need to be consistent. Either use Apache and give the (same) builder *both* `loadKeyMaterial` *and* `loadTrustMaterial` corresponding to what you want -- in particular httpclient 4.5.4 adds `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustAllStrategy` which implements "cheerfully let all thieves and crooks see and change my supposedly secure data". Alternatively, use JSSE to directly create an `SSLContext` with `.getInstance()` and `.init()` it (once!) with your zero-security trustmanager and a keymanager created from your keystore (and an explicit `SecureRandom` if you like but if you omit that it defaults).

However, this may not work because the `keytool` command you show is correct only if `yourdomain` was a pre-existing PrivateKeyEntry matching the cert chain you imported to it. Use `keytool -list -alias yourdomain` to make sure it's a PrivateKeyEntry and NOT a TrustedCertEntry. If not, and if you need to use the privatekey from the PEM file (rather than one already in a keystore) you need to first convert the key *and* cert chain to PKCS12 with OpenSSL, and then depending on your Java *maybe* convert the PKCS12 to JKS with `keytool`. There are dozens of Qs (and As) on several Stacks for this.

Comment: i'll convert to pkcs12 and everything works okay , i install my cert with InstallCert.java , thank you , also i change  HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).  to 
 HttpClients.custom().setSSLFactory(factory)